# How do you measure the PHP generation time of your Wordpress pages?

Tags: php, performance

I'd like to measure the PHP page generation time for my Wordpress sites, preferrably without any plugin.

Which PHP files would you edit to do this?

I was thinking about adding this in `index.php`:

```
<?php
$generation_time_start = microtime(true);
```

and in the `footer.php` (add in very small text font with CSS)

```
<?php
$generation_time_end = microtime(true);
echo ($generation_time_end - $generation_time_start)*1000;
```

Is this a reliable way to measure the page generation time?

How would you do it?

Comment: Why the objection to using a plugin - that's the great thing about Open Source, you can learn a lot about coding by reading how other people resolve things - I would suggest you read over the code in the Query Monitor plugin to load how to do what you want to do.

Comment: @QStudio I use a few plugins for important tasks, which is great. But I try to keep the number of plugins the lowest as possible for small tasks like this, because, eventually, you have lots of problems like "This plugin is no more updated / not compatible with this new version of Wordpress" and I'd like to avoid this on long term. So if possible, I'd prefer a 100% PHP solution in a few lines of code.

Comment: Sure, it's good to be selective before you use a plugin - you can usually tell which are active and will continue to be used by looking at latest update date, github activity and size of the community they have - as I mentioned, this plugin does what you need, just read over the code - https://github.com/johnbillion/query-monitor

Comment: Ok I'll look into this @QStudio. Side-question: can I define custom global PHP variables in `index.php` (like `$generation_time_start`), and keep them in all future PHP files which are called, such as `footer.php`?

Comment: You can, or just use a class and properties - define then at the first hook, retrieve them on the last, such as "shutdown"